# How is $X+X'Y = X+Y$?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have been searching online and the answer I am getting is not making sense to me.

My professor wrote on the board:
$$X+X'Y = (X+X')(X+Y) = X+Y.$$

But I am not understanding where is he getting $(X+X')(X+Y)$ from?

I know that $(X+X') = 1$ so $1*(X+Y) = X+Y. $

[The picture attached is the list of all the Duality Principle we are using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Cku.png)

Comment: What mathematical discipline is this?  Calculus?  Symbolic logic?  What?  Please as a more detailed question, with context, if you seek help.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - It looks like Boolean algebra with $X'$ being the complement of $X$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Apply $(T8')~~X+Y\cdot Z=(X+Y)\cdot(X+Z)$ on $X+X'\cdot Y$ see what you get.

Comment: so all I had to do is let z = x'. Then I'd get (X+Y)(X+X') = (X+Y)(1) = (X+Y). I got it. Do you have any suggestion how to solve these kind of questions quickly? They are easy once you see them but really hard when can't notice the pattern.

Comment: @kazisiam In general If you familiar with those laws, I believe  you will solve these kind of questions quickly, see also [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), if you familiar with logic, they are the same.